# Spring MVC - Context initialization failed after rename /WEB-INF/tasks-servlet.xml

Tags: xml, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, model-view-controller

I changed the name of /WEB-INF/tasks-servlet.xml to /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml but when I reboot the server I get this error. It still look for the former file (/WEB-INF/tasks-servlet.xml)

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/tasks-servlet.xml]; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tasks-servlet.xml]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the web.xml. The name of the xml context should be the same as the dispatcher servlet + `"-servlet"`. Probably your dispatcher servlet is named `tasks`.
You have to rename the servlet to `"mvc-dispatcher"`